# Issues with jQuery.inArray()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a array with IDs. Any element with a data-functionID that isn't in the array should be removed.So I loop through all elements with the attribute data-functionID and if the ID doesn't exist in the array, it is removed.

Now my problem is that jQuery.inArray() always returns -1 (in the variable access) and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
//html-example
<button data-functionID="j1_1" onclick="doStuff()">Button 1</button>
<button data-functionID="j1_24" onclick="doOtherStuff()">Button 2</button>
```

The array defined below is written with PHP using a mysqli_fecth_all-query that I simply save in a variable `$role`, that a encode to JSON:

```
var role = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($role)?>');
```

After PHP it looks like this:

```
// defining array
var role = JSON.parse('[["j1_1"],["j1_24"],["j1_63"],["j1_62"],["j1_61"],["j1_60"],["j1_59"],["j1_57"],["j1_58"],["j1_56"],["j1_55"],["j1_54"],["j1_53"],["j1_51"],["j1_52"],["j1_50"],["j1_49"],["j1_48"],["j1_47"],["j1_46"],["j1_45"],["j1_44"],["j1_43"],["j1_42"],["j1_41"],["j1_40"],["j1_39"],["j1_38"],["j1_37"],["j1_36"],["j1_35"],["j1_34"],["j1_33"],["j1_32"],["j1_31"],["j1_30"],["j1_29"],["j1_28"],["j1_27"],["j1_26"],["j1_25"],["j1_23"],["j1_22"],["j1_21"],["j1_20"],["j1_19"],["j1_18"],["j1_17"],["j1_16"],["j1_15"],["j1_14"],["j1_13"],["j1_12"],["j1_11"],["j1_10"],["j1_9"],["j1_8"],["j1_7"],["j1_6"],["j1_5"],["j1_4"],["j1_3"],["j1_2"]]');

// test
$("[data-functionID]").each(function(e){
  functionID = $(this).attr('data-functionID');
  var access = jQuery.inArray(functionID, role);
  console.log(functionID + ':' + access);
  if(access == -1){
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: What is 'access'?  Every element in the role array is a sub array with a value.  If you are trying to find the value, it will not match against any of the first level arrays.  string === array is never true.  Also I question why you have an array filled with sub arrays with only a single element in them.  Imho, that's a data model smell.

Comment: Add `functionID` and `role` example to your question.

Comment: The array looks like this because I simply let PHP write it from a mysqli_fetch_all-query that I JSON-encode into the javascript. Is there any way I could use a similair test for the same array, or is the best way to not use the one from the mysqli-query, and make your own?

Comment: I added explanation to the array and functionID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my problem with changing the array to be created from a `mysqli_query` to loop through a `mysqli_fetch_assoc` and creating the array manually to get a one-dimensional array.

```
$role = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $role[] = $row['functionID'];
}
```

Which gives the javascript output as an one-dimensional array:

```
var role = JSON.parse('["j1_1","j1_24","j1_63","j1_62","j1_61","j1_60","j1_59","j1_57","j1_58","j1_56","j1_55","j1_54","j1_53","j1_51","j1_52","j1_50","j1_49","j1_48","j1_47","j1_46","j1_45","j1_44","j1_43","j1_42","j1_41","j1_40","j1_39","j1_38","j1_37","j1_36","j1_35","j1_34","j1_33","j1_32","j1_31","j1_30","j1_29","j1_28","j1_27","j1_26","j1_25","j1_23","j1_22","j1_21","j1_20","j1_19","j1_18","j1_17","j1_16","j1_15","j1_14","j1_13","j1_12","j1_11","j1_10","j1_9","j1_8","j1_7","j1_6","j1_5","j1_4","j1_3","j1_2"]');
```